# Getting "No controller returned error" from Ninject only in certain environments with MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I am currently creating an MVC3 application using Ninject. I have two controllers which get injected with a repository by Ninject, both of which work fine on my local machine.

However, when I deploy them to my remote web server, I get `The IControllerFactory 'Inventory.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'GetOptions'.` as an error, but only when I hit one of the controllers - the other works fine. Is there something that I'm doing wrong here? I'm pretty new to Ninject and DI so if there is another way I should be going about this, please let me know. Thanks!

Here is my controller factory

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IVehicleRepository>().To<EFVehicleRepository>();
    }
}
```

In Application_Start I have:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

And last, my controllers are

```
public class InventoryAPIController : Controller
{
    IVehicleRepository repository;

    public InventoryAPIController(IVehicleRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;

    }
}
```

and

```
public class VehicleController : Controller
{


    IVehicleRepository repository;

    public VehicleController(IVehicleRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Ninject.MVC3 found on nuget instead of your custom controller factory. It uses DependencyResolver instead of a ControllerFactory, which is the prefered way for MVC3.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize there was an MVC3 specific version, will try that tomorrow, thanks!